# Custom intent targeting a specific package

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

Say my app is "A", I start an activity of an app "B" using custom intent from the app "A". It works fine as I would want it to. The code I use is, in manifest of app "B":

```
<activity
        android:name=".mysecondAct"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.intent.action.Dream" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In my activity from app "A", I start app "B" with,

```
Intent i =new Intent("com.example.intent.action.Dream");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Now, how do I specify a specific package to which the intent should be sent to so that, only that app receives the intent and start the activity? The reason is, I have a list of package and the user chooses which one to call.

Answer (score 11):

Use the ComponentName class like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example1", "com.example1.MyExampleActivity1"));

startActivity(intent);
```

Pls note that the first argument is not the package name of the class; it is the package name of the application---the package attribute of the manifest element in that application's AndroidManifest.xml.

If you know the name of the activity to be started (not the class) then you can do something like this:

```
Class<?> claz = null;

if(StringClassname != null) {

    try {

        claz = Class.forName(StringClassname );

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

Intent intent = new Intent(this, claz);

startActivity(intent);
```

And, in case you don't even know the activity name and the corresponding class, then I guess it becomes a candidate for using broadcast i.e. From you AppA, you should be broadcasting..and have broadcast receiver in AppB,AppC etc with corresponding filters..

Edit: Given that you are just aware of the package name and the intent action name, try creating your intent like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();

i.setAction("com.example.intent.action.Dream");

i.setPackage(packageName);

startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue here is, I want to start the activity with my custom intent which here is: "com.example.intent.action.Dream" and set the target to a specific package. 
What I mean is, I know the package of the app which I should start but not the class. So I set the intent to that specific package and the activity receives the intent and responds

Comment: Still I think the answer doesnt help me and I guess you didn't get my point. The situation is, There are many apps (say 10) having a activity with the intent filter "com.example.intent.action.Dream". Now from my master app "A", I send out an startActivity() with my custom intent which would only target one of the 10 apps in the list for which I know the package names already

Comment: Thank you. That solves my problem but I found it out by doing a little more extensive search and I have posted it too without knowing your edit. So there seems to be 2 exactly same answers. Is it ok if its left as it is?

Comment: Well my edited answer says 'edited 17 mins ago', and your posted answer says 'answered 11 mins ago', so technically ...  ;)

Comment: Yes by the time stamp say, its you. But I'm not notified of the edits. I'm notified only when you comment. So, you what happened there :P Any I'll leave it as it is and any experienced user who knows what to do shall do what should be done

Answer (score 5):

So the fix was very simple. I just set the package in intent to which package my intent should be passed. The code is:

```
Intent i =new Intent("com.example.intent.action.Dream");
i.setPackage("com.package.to.start"); //The package name of the app to which intent is to be sent
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```